# Adding drop down sub menu to code

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add a drop down menu to this code but always seem to get turned around. I just want a basic look to the subnav with a simple rollover effect. Every time i try different code it uses home image in the drop down menu and will not disappear when it is not hovered over. Ideas?

HTML:

```
   <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="navbar1"><a href="home.html" title="Home">Home</a>
      <ul class="subnav"> 
               <li><a href="#">Menu 1 </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Menu 2 </a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>

    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.navbar {
width:1000px;
list-style:none;
height:40px;
}
ul.navbar li {
display:inline;
}
ul.navbar li a {
height:40px;
float:left;
text-indent:-9999px;
}
/* Home 0 */
ul.navbar li.navbar1 a {
width:86px;
background:url(../pelican%20outfitters/navbar2.fw.png)
 no-repeat 0 0; 
}
ul.navbar  li.navbar1 a:hover {
background-position:0 -40px; 
}
ul.navbar  li.navbar1 a.current {
background-position:0 -80px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the `text-indent:-9999px` and add this to your css

Delete row:

```
ul.navbar li a { text-indent:-9999px }
```

Css:

```
.navbar li ul {display:none;}
.navbar li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

Than you have a basic navbar with hidden subnavs. 
From here you can try it with your image.

The demo is your code with the new code..

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B7HSv/)**

More like you want is, dont delete the css.. but only add those 2 lines and this 1:

```
.navbar li:hover li a{ text-indent:1px; background:white; }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/B7HSv/4/)** *(without your img (don't know what it is)).*

**Latest update after the fiddle comment:**

You should specify your html and css.. a just added a class to the first link `class="home"` and to accomodations `class="accomodations"`

And changed it in the css..

```
/* Home */
ul.navbar li.navbar1 a.home {
   width:86px;
   background:url(http://s12.postimg.org/rszejjscd/navbar2_fw.png)
   no-repeat 0 0; 
}
/* Accomodations */
   ul.navbar li.navbar2 a.accomodations {
   width:220px;
   background: url(http://s12.postimg.org/rszejjscd/navbar2_fw.png) no-repeat -86px 0;
}
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/xhB2J/1/)**

Comment: I added these three lines of code. This is what I am getting now, the hidden subnav  when hovered over shoots out to the right in the div and pushes my next nav main menu over. Example Home,Home,Home,Home,Home,Home, Accomodations.Then when not hovered over it will go back to Example Home, Accomodations. I tried position absolute but that made it worse. Also the style you recommended is not showing up. It is still using the image from my nav bar, Would rather simple CSS kind of what fiddle posted above for the look of the subnav with a simple rollover.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your image inside? So i can see whats wrong?

Comment: In your demo the subnavmeu for home shoots right, I need it to shoot down and be able to customize the css for the subnav.

Comment: Here is my latest, I started coding the rest of my menu in the mean time. I set position to absolute which is creating my vertical navbar, yahhhh, but it is only displaying one menu. The navbar has a black space on the left side of it. Lastly the images still cant be formated for the subnav.    http://jsfiddle.net/mitchelll182/Z7kB2/1/

Comment: Im trying to make it work, hang on. 1 thing, add `padding:0;` to you `<ul>`

Comment: Heading to work, I'll give it another crack tomorrow. The absolute position doesn't really help I don't think. Never thought it would be this difficult for a navbar. I really appreciate this a lot.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. If you find a way I can return the favor let me know. Thank you so so so so so much.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
   <nav>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li class="navbar1"><a href="home.html" title="Home">Home</a>
    
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 1 </a>
    
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 2 </a>
    
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li
{
    width:100px;
}

ul li ul li
{  width:200px;

}
nav ul {
    font-size: 25px;
    background: white;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: black;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #2E2E2E;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtwdR/6/)

Comment: Amarnath How would I dd my current, active, and hover image to this? Each image would have a different size as well. This is the issue I ran into before because even when I did enter in my image it would not show the  whole image, only a portion of it.